# VF - SCC - Event. How to refresh data table when new event created for a user using standard page layout

Tags: streaming-api

This is to those who are currently using the Steaming API / pushtopics within a Visualforce page in Salesforce classic / the Service Cloud Console. We have a VF page displaying the users event data (as well as task data). We allow the user to click on a new event button which, in another tab, utilizes that standard page layout for event entry. The user hits save and the tab closes and they return to their event list tab. How can we refresh this list after the addition of a new event. (With tasks we use pushtopics and it works great). (Note we'd rather not have to rewrite the standard event record entry in VF due to the LOE it would take. Thanks!

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based and very difficult to effectively answer.

Comment: Disagree. This is censorship at it's worst and is not the spirit of the forum. I'm simply asking for the technical reasons of why, when there are 2 very similar objects, 1 is supported and 1 is not supported. ie. is it due to possible performance hits on the platform..etc.etc.  This is no positive or negative opinion at all in this question.

Comment: You're asking people to postulate about something where knowledge is unlikely to be available. There are some internal salesforce guys on here, but even they might not be able to say.

Comment: Ok. fair enough.  Let me rephrase the question.  This is to those who are currently using the Steaming API / pushtopics within a Visualforce page in Salesforce classic / the Service Cloud Console. We have a VF page displaying the users event data (as well as task data).  We allow the user to click on a new event button which, in another tab, utilizes that standard page layout for event entry. The user hits save and the tab closes and they return to their event list tab.  How can we refresh this list after the addition of a new event. (With tasks we use pushtopics and it works great). Thanks!

Comment: Can you actually edit the question with that? Once you have you can nominate it for re-opening.